# Table border="0" show on print

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4.5.6 and put a table without borders (border="0"), but, when i click to print the content, the table shows dotted border on print preview. How can i solve this?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

By default ckeditor ads the dotted borders (it adds the class cke_show_border to the table element). To get rid of this, you can either modify the css for the ckeditor (contents.css in the ckeditor directory), and remove/edit the style for that class, or you can modify the ckeditor core code so that it doesn't add this class to the table when you're editing it (it removes that class when you submit the text).

Simplest is just to modify the contents.css, editing the core code is a bit harder, and you will have to repackage ckeditor.js.

Comment: Hi, i liked the dotted border when the user are editing...i want to take off this only when user will print the content. I think that if the user put border = "0", he wants no border, even when printing.
The CKEditor team should check this issue, i thought!
Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: How are you printing the content? Are you printing it from the webpage after submitting the contents of the editor?

You can change the css too. For the ckeditor css, I think it is contents.css that you can find in the ckeditor directory. If it's outside of the editor, just make another css file.

Comment: I'm printing by click on the print button in editor. I will have to do different, i have to get the content of editor, take off the dotted border in this code, and send to print.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by unminifying the file ckeditor.js, there was a showborders function responsible for adding the "dotted" borders when I changed it resolved

**Before**

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.add("showborders", {
        modes: {
            wysiwyg: 1
        },
        onLoad: function() {
            var a;
            a = (CKEDITOR.env.ie6Compat ? [".%1 table.%2,", ".%1 table.%2 td, .%1 table.%2 th", "{", "border : #d3d3d3 1px dotted", "}"] : ".%1 table.%2,;.%1 table.%2 \x3e tr \x3e td, .%1 table.%2 \x3e tr \x3e th,;.%1 table.%2 \x3e tbody \x3e tr \x3e td, .%1 table.%2 \x3e tbody \x3e tr \x3e th,;.%1 table.%2 \x3e thead \x3e tr \x3e td, .%1 table.%2 \x3e thead \x3e tr \x3e th,;.%1 table.%2 \x3e tfoot \x3e tr \x3e td, .%1 table.%2 \x3e tfoot \x3e tr \x3e th;{;border : #d3d3d3 1px dotted;}".split(";")).join("").replace(/%2/g,
                "cke_show_border_old ").replace(/%1/g, "a ");
            CKEDITOR.addCss(a)
        },
        init: function(a) {
            var b = a.addCommand("showborders", f);
            b.canUndo = !1;
            !1 !== a.config.startupShowBorders && b.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON);
            a.on("mode", function() {
                b.state != CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED && b.refresh(a)
            }, null, null, 100);
            a.on("contentDom", function() {
                b.state != CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED && b.refresh(a)
            });
            a.on("removeFormatCleanup", function(d) {
                d = d.data;
                a.getCommand("showborders").state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON && d.is("table") && (!d.hasAttribute("border") ||
                    0 >= parseInt(d.getAttribute("border"), 10)) && d.addClass("cke_show_border_old ")
            })
        },
        afterInit: function(a) {
            var b = a.dataProcessor;
            a = b && b.dataFilter;
            b = b && b.htmlFilter;
            a && a.addRules({
                elements: {
                    table: function(a) {
                        a = a.attributes;
                        var b = a["class"],
                            c = parseInt(a.border, 10);
                        c && !(0 >= c) || b && -1 != b.indexOf("cke_show_border_old ") || (a["class"] = (b || "") + " cke_show_border_old ")
                    }
                }
            });
            b && b.addRules({
                elements: {
                    table: function(a) {
                        a = a.attributes;
                        var b = a["class"];
                        b && (a["class"] = b.replace("cke_show_border_old ", "").replace(/\s{2}/, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,
                            ""))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

**Now**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add("showborders", {
        modes: {
            wysiwyg: 1
        },
        onLoad: function() {
            console.log("try to add border")
        },
        init: function(a) {
            var b = a.addCommand("showborders", f);
            b.canUndo = !1;
            !1 !== a.config.startupShowBorders && b.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON);
            a.on("mode", function() {
                console.log("try to add border")
            }, null, null, 100);
            a.on("contentDom", function() {
                console.log("try to add border")
            });
            a.on("removeFormatCleanup", function(d) {
               console.log("try to add border")
           })
        },
        afterInit: function(a) {
            var b = a.dataProcessor;
            a = b && b.dataFilter;
            b = b && b.htmlFilter;
            a && a.addRules({
                elements: {
                    table: function(a) {
                        a = a.attributes;
                        var b = a["class"],
                            c = parseInt(a.border, 10);
                        c && !(0 >= c) || b && -1 != b.indexOf("cke_show_border ") || (a["class"] = (b || "") + " cke_show_border ")
                    }
                }
            });
            b && b.addRules({
                elements: {
                    table: function(a) {
                        a = a.attributes;
                        var b = a["class"];
                        b && (a["class"] = b.replace("cke_show_border ", "").replace(/\s{2}/, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,
                            ""))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
```